# separating a .txt file into two columns using pandas

Tags: pandas, csv, export-to-csv, data-cleaning

I have a text file of a script and is ordered like this:

```
0 "character one" "dialogue for character one."
1 "character two" "dialogue for character two." 
2 "character one" "dialogue for character one again"
...
etc
```

My problem is that I want to analyze this text and need it to be in .csv format where the character is in the first column, and the dialogue is all in the second column.

I have read the .txt file into pandas like so:

`txt_ep_4 = pd.read_table('/Users/nathancahn/star_wars/0_data/ep_IV_script.txt')`
so now I have a pandas data series (not a data frame) to interact with.

I've mostly tried different methods of splitting the text into columns with Series.str.split() but have been unsuccessful. I used `series_txt_ep_4.str.split(pat=" ")` to indicate separating at the space but this instead separated at every space.

Again, my ideal output would be to have the first column be the character name and the second column be the string of dialogue associated with that character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) with parameters `sep` and `names` for new columns names, because in `pandas 0.24.2` get:

> FutureWarning: read_table is deprecated, use read_csv instead.

```
temp=u'''"character one" "dialogue for character one."
"character two" "dialogue for character two." 
"character one" "dialogue for character one again"'''
#after testing replace 'pd.compat.StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(temp), sep="\s+", names=['a','b'])
#alternative
#df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(temp), delim_whitespace=True, names=['a','b'])
print (df)
               a                                 b
0  character one       dialogue for character one.
1  character two       dialogue for character two.
2  character one  dialogue for character one again
```

EDIT:

If values have also header:

```
temp=u""""character" "dialogue"
"1" "THREEPIO" "Did you hear that?  They've shut down the main reactor.  We'll be destroyed for sure.  This is madness!"
"2" "THREEPIO" "We're doomed!"
"3" "THREEPIO" "There'll be no escape for the Princess this time."
"4" "THREEPIO" "What's that?"
"5" "THREEPIO" "I should have known better than to trust the logic of a half-sized thermocapsulary dehousing assister..."
"6" "LUKE" "Hurry up!  Come with me!  What are you waiting for?!  Get in gear!"
"7" "THREEPIO" "Artoo! Artoo-Detoo, where are you?"
"8" "THREEPIO" "At last!  Where have you been?"
"9" "THREEPIO" "They're heading in this direction. What are we going to do?  We'll be sent to the spice mines of Kessel or smashed into who knows what!"
"10" "THREEPIO" "Wait a minute, where are you going?"
"""
#after testing replace 'pd.compat.StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(temp), sep="\s+")
```

---

```
print (df)

   character                                           dialogue
1   THREEPIO  Did you hear that?  They've shut down the main...
2   THREEPIO                                      We're doomed!
3   THREEPIO  There'll be no escape for the Princess this time.
4   THREEPIO                                       What's that?
5   THREEPIO  I should have known better than to trust the l...
6       LUKE  Hurry up!  Come with me!  What are you waiting...
7   THREEPIO                 Artoo! Artoo-Detoo, where are you?
8   THREEPIO                     At last!  Where have you been?
9   THREEPIO  They're heading in this direction. What are we...
10  THREEPIO                Wait a minute, where are you going?
```

Comment: Ah interesting, this looks like the right direction. Not sure if I 100% understand this code though however. So is `temp` here supposed to be the pd.series that I pass? Because I'm getting an error when trying to read a pd.series into this.

Comment: @NathanCahn - No, dont pass Series, use `txt_ep_4 = pd.read_csv('/Users/nathancahn/star_wars/0_data/ep_IV_script.txt', sep="\s+", names=['a','b'])`

Comment: Ah okay, it seems that gave a pandas data frame that cut off after the "character" and is now not including the dialogue. I am realizing now that this might be because of the fact that my .txt file actually includes an index number before the "character" column. Like so:

```
"1" "character" "dialogue"
"2" "character" "dialogue"
etc
```

Comment: @NathanCahn - Are data confidental?

Comment: @NathanCahn - because the best is working with file, if some quoting and similar, If paste values to question, is possible some values should be changed. so is possible upload first 5 rows with file to gdocs, dropbox or similar and share link?

Comment: I see I see. Here is a link to a google doc with the top of the data copy and pasted in https://docs.google.com/document/d/1eeiA3Ghz8wp5IqbUjiiJO9nc3ciOaYb6VZ7P_vtstF4/edit

Comment: @NathanCahn - `You need permission` I got

Comment: Never mind, this link should work!

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1eeiA3Ghz8wp5IqbUjiiJO9nc3ciOaYb6VZ7P_vtstF4/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @NathanCahn - No problem, my email is in my profile, only run code :)